# how do I find the name of a row with the highest value, while making it apply to only columns and rows that have certain letters in them?

Tags: r, dataframe

this is a bit of a wordy question, but I am going to try my best to explain what I mean. I am trying to find which row has the highest value, but only the rows that being with 'P'. Additionally, the data I am finding must only come from columns labelled with an 'X' or a 'Y'.

I have tried the following
 `which.max(starts_with('P', vars = rownames (df)))`

which returns '7', which isn't what i am looking for as am trying to find the row name and

`apply(df,2, function(x) rownames(starts_with('P' , vars = rownames (df)[which.max(x)])))`

which returns 'NULL'

I am not too sure where to go from here so any help would be appreciated

Comment: it's always good to provide some sample data using the `dput()` function along with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of methods. In base R, you just index the rows and columns you want. With `tidyverse`, the key is `across` and `filter`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(325)
example <- data.frame(X = runif(10),
                      Y = runif(10),
                      Z = runif(10))
rownames(example) <- paste0(rep(c("P", "Q"), each = 5), letters[1:10])

example
#>             X         Y          Z
#> Pa 0.28562643 0.6374726 0.79912255
#> Pb 0.77826216 0.2865916 0.25675714
#> Pc 0.17755904 0.3224505 0.09088556
#> Pd 0.17746066 0.4826326 0.91427141
#> Pe 0.05051595 0.6313907 0.78323084
#> Qf 0.52700377 0.4737712 0.72399495
#> Qg 0.21432109 0.6930352 0.83874507
#> Qh 0.05371255 0.8982120 0.56664176
#> Qi 0.70414724 0.6843163 0.56803104
#> Qj 0.33675891 0.1237741 0.75540541

#base R solution
example[grepl("^P", rownames(example)), c("X", "Y")] |>
  (\(k)apply(k, 2, \(j) rownames(k)[which.max(j)]))()
#>    X    Y 
#> "Pb" "Pa"

#tidyverse solution
example |>
  rownames_to_column("col") |>
  filter(grepl("^P", col)) |>
  summarise(across(c(X,Y), \(v) col[which.max(v)]))
#>    X  Y
#> 1 Pb Pa
```